# KnockoutJS Sortable BeforeMove

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use the KnockoutJS sortable plugin's `beforeMove` event which is outlined here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

In my app, users should only be able to nest categories to two levels:

```
- Cat 1
    - Cat 1.1
    - Cat 1.2
        - Cat 1.2.1 <-- Not allowed
```

Currently, I am trying to access "targetParent" and "item" from the event's "args" parameter.

I can test whether the item being moved has any children (true/false). But I also need to check whether the intended "parent" is the rootline.

Because, if the current item has children and the intended parent is NOT the rootline, then I want to cancel as it would lead to three levels.

Now, I have spent hours looking at targetParent, sourceParent and all the other information and I can't for the life of me figure out how it works.

Any pointers as to accessing the *real* intended parent-item would be amazing. If it is rootline, it should return NULL, if it is an object, I would need to get the object.

Long story short: I need to find the *one* target that my item is being dropped into. This could be NULL, or **one** object which the user dropped the item in to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arg` coming into `beforeMove` will have `arg.item` set as the item being dropped and `arg.targetParent` as the observableArray that it is being dropped into.  So, if you had a view model something like:

```
var Item = function(name, children) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = ko.observableArray(children || []);
};

var ViewModel = function() {
   var self = this;
   this.root = new Item("1", [
        new Item("1.1", [
            new Item("1.1.1"),
            new Item("1.1.2")
        ]),
        new Item("1.2", [
            new Item("1.2.1"),
            new Item("1.2.2")
        ])
   ]);


   this.beforeMoveCheck = function(arg) {
      var cancel = arg.item.children().length && arg.targetParent !== self.root.children;
      console.log("cancelling", !!cancel);
      arg.cancelDrop = !!cancel;
   };
};
```

Then the `beforeMove` would set `arg.cancelDrop` based on whether `arg.item` has any children and whether the new parent was the root's children.

Here is a sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/yfAEZawfWxdu1yBdtlDR?p=preview

Comment: Hi RPN, thanks so much for the example - it all works flawlessly. However, I am not quite sure why it returns a value as targetParent when dropping it on the root - I kept thinking it should return null. Anyhow, thank you again. :)

Comment: the targetParent is the observableArray that it is being dropped into, in that case it is the root's `children`. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Well, thanks to you! :-) ... I suppose I got confused as my root is not a category. The root is a simple observableArray which contains the "rootline"-categories - therefore, it behaves in a way that I did not really understand.